# Sinónimos: ¿Una respuesta cierta es una respuesta correcta?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado-en-contexto

Sé que lo más común es decir "una respuesta correcta" en lugar de "una respuesta cierta" en español cuando se habla de una respuesta sin errores. Sin embargo, hoy vi un texto de las Naciones Unidas cuya [traducción del inglés al español](https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N09/287/01/PDF/N0928701.pdf?OpenElement)  menciona "una respuesta cierta":

[Original en inglés](https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N09/286/98/pdf/N0928698.pdf?OpenElement):

> In order to close the files of the 369 missing Kuwaiti and
> third-country nationals, their mortal remains need to be (a) found;
> (b) exhumed; (c) transported to Kuwait; and (d) identified. (...) In some cases, DNA analysis cannot produce a **definite answer**.

Traducción al español:

> A fin de cerrar los expedientes de los 369 nacionales de Kuwait y de terceros países aún desaparecidos, es necesario que sus restos mortales sean a) hallados; b) exhumados; c) transportados a Kuwait; d) identificados. (...) En algunos casos el análisis de ADN no puede arrojar una **respuesta cierta**.

Una de las definiciones del diccionario DLE de "[cierto](https://dle.rae.es/cierto)" es "conocido como verdadero, seguro, indubitable", así que creo que el texto habla de una "respuesta segura, indubitable" y no de una "respuesta correcta".

¿"respuesta cierta" puede ser un sinónimo de "respuesta correcta" en español?

Comment: El enlace a la traducción del texto no me funciona: me lleva a una página de error. No sé si es solo problema mío. Quizá puedes copiar la frase relevante aquí?

Comment: @wimi Añadí la frase relevante a mi pregunta.

Comment: Sí, "cierto" en este caso se refiere a  certero, preciso. Respecto a tu segunda pregunta, sí se usa en ocasiones cierta en vez de correcta, aunque es posible que más como sustituto de verdarera. La imagen que me viene a la mente es la de un cocurso de televisión y el presentador le dice al concursante: _¡Veamos si es cierta_ (verdadera) _tu respuesta!_, aunque "correcta" también podría usarse.

Comment: @wimi He encontrado los documentos (original en inglés y traducción oficial al español ) e incluido esa información en la pregunta.

Comment: "Una respuesta acertada"  es otra posiblidad.

Comment: @WalterMitty Al igual que right no es sinónimo de definite, acertada no es sinónimo de concluyente, que es la palabra indicada en mi opinión. Creo que acertado o correcto son adecuados para otros contextos como un examen o un concurso de televisión pero no para este. Aprovecho para añadir esto a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Considero que "cierto" y "correcto" en este contexto no son completamente sinónimos. Y además que "cierto" no es una traducción adecuada para "definite" en relación a estos textos.

De acuerdo con el diccionario Cambridge Inglés-Español:

> [definite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/definite) 
> *certain, clear, and not likely to change*
>  (ES) definitivo

Como profesional IT, tiendo a asociar que algo es cierto o falso a un valor binario, 0 ó 1, true o false.

En el caso que nos ocupa la identificación de una coincidencia de ADN del 68% es **cierta y correcta**. Por un lado, se corresponde con los resultados obtenidos (cierto/verdadero) y por otro no se han producido errores durante el procedimiento (correcto), pero quizás **no sea definitiva o concluyente**. Esa respuesta cierta y correcta, no permite identificar sin ningún género de dudas que unos restos se correspondan a una determinada persona.

Si asociamos cierto con **preciso**, puede que los resultados obtenidos sean muy precisos, una coincidencia del 68,3437846486985% pero que siga sin ser concluyente para permitir una identificación.

Por tanto, en este contexto yo hubiera empleado el adjetivo **concluyente**.

@WalterMitty apunta en los comentarios el adjetivo **acertado** pero al igual que *right* no es sinónimo de *definite* aquí, acertado no puede reemplazar a concluyente en este contexto. Creo que acertado/correcto pueden emplearse perfectamente en un examen o un concurso de televisión pero no aquí.

Answer (score 4):

**Respuesta Rápida**
Respuesta *cierta* y respuesta *correcta* son equivalentes en una charla casual. Por otro lado, como traducción de *definite*, en el texto que propones, yo preferiría *definitiva*, *concluyente* o *clara*.

---

Uso de *Respuesta correcta*
Si estamos hablando de la respuesta de un estudiante en una prueba, lo mas natural es decir *respuesta correcta* (o incorrecta).

Uso de *Respuesta cierta*
Aquí *cierta* puede ser equivalente de *correcta* pero también puede significar que es una respuesta que no da lugar a dudas. Para ejemplificar mejor, puedes considerar el opuesto.

> Las respuestas del acusado eran inciertas

No necesariamente significa que erró al responder pero también que las respuestas eran dudosas.

Por este motivo, que la prueba de ADN nos arroje una *respuesta cierta*, a mi me evoca el significado de *definitivo*, *concluyente*, *claro*, *indiscutible*.

---

A continuación aporto algunas de las alternativas disponibles:

> ... el análisis de ADN no puede arrojar una respuesta *definitiva*
> ... el análisis de ADN no puede arrojar una respuesta *concluyente*
> ... el análisis de ADN no puede arrojar una respuesta *clara*
> ... el análisis de ADN no puede arrojar una respuesta *indiscutible*

Comment: Lo de "Respuesta rápida" confunde un poco cuando a continuación pones "Respuesta cierta y respuesta correcta". En tu ejemplo del acusado, no queda claro si esas respuestas eran falsas o es que el sujeto mostraba duda al darlas. La frase es ambigua. Por otro lado, las dos alternativas que das coinciden exactamente con las que ya había aportado yo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que estaba confuso así que lo edité para que estuviera mas claro. En cuanto a la confusión con el ejemplo del acusado, el hecho de que sea ambiguo refuerza el punto de que incierto e incorrecto no son equivalentes siempre (y por lo tanto cierto y correcto). Estoy de acuerdo en que hay que aportar algo nuevo así que hice ediciones adicionales.